# How does Uber PIN ("Verify my Ride") feature secure anything?

Tags: driver, formal-verification

Haven't been using Uber for quite a while and now just bumped into this feature called "[Verify my Ride](https://help.uber.com/riders/article/whats-verify-my-ride/?nodeId=2ddbb5e8-0dd3-4048-b9ee-f6b5e5311e25)":

> Verify Your Ride is a PIN verification feature that provides an
> optional extra layer of protection to **ensure you’re getting into the
> right vehicle with the right driver**. You can choose to opt into this
> feature for added peace of mind on every ride.
>
> After opting in, you’ll receive a unique 4-digit PIN whenever you
> request a ride. Before entering your driver’s vehicle, tell them your
> PIN; if they are the driver the app matched you with, they’ll be able
> to start the trip after they enter your PIN into their app.

What prevents an imposter driver (who wishes an unsuspecting Uber user to sit in their car) from **pretending** that they successfully enter into their app whatever PIN the user gives them, and just starting to drive? The user isn't supposed to inspect the driver's phone/app. Is there some sort of confirmation that the user receives in *their* app once the driver enters the PIN?

I would understand the feature if it was other way around: the driver tells the user the PIN, the user enters it in their app which confirms that the driver is the genuine one.

Also, from my experience, Uber always tells the user the vehicle plate number. What's the point in this PIN verification then if you can just look at the plate? For the case where some dude desperately wishing to give the user a lift manages to promptly fabricate and attach fake plate to their car?

Answer (score 1):

It's to protect you against a driver that does not pick you up and charges you.

You and Uber are the ones who have the PIN, the driver does not. When the drives comes to pick you, you tell him the PIN and he enters it on their app. If the PIN matches, the ride begins to be charged on you, and the driver knows he got the right passenger.

That started being used because some drivers would just pretend to have picked you up and drive around charging you. That's why Uber tells you to only tell the PIN to the driver when he arrives, and don't tell them by chat.

Comment: Nice theory. However, _where_ does Uber tell "you to only tell the PIN to the driver when he arrives, and don't tell them by chat"? I see it says "Before entering your driver’s vehicle, tell them your PIN". And the declared purpose is "to ensure you’re getting into the right vehicle with the right driver", not to avoid being charged without being given the lift.

Comment: It's not a theory, it's the message Uber gives its users in Brazil. This [article](https://www.moneytimes.com.br/uber-motoristas-aplicam-golpe-com-codigo-de-seguranca-entenda/) in Portuguese explains it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is mostly so the Driver can authenticate that the user is the correct one, and not someone looking for a free trip on someone else's Uber, as you said, you authenticate the driver by looking the license plate.

As you said again, the driver should give you a pin to enter, hopefully Uber will add this feature too.

Comment: Makes sense, but this goes against how the feature is explained by Uber: "_ensure you’re getting into the right vehicle with the right driver_".

Comment: You could tell the PIN outside the car by the window, and wait for your app to tell you that this is indeed your ride.

Comment: Do you know it for sure that my app will confirm when the driver enters PIN in his app, or are you just guessing? The Uber site does not say anything about the user's app confirming.